# How to play an audio file in a infinite loop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mp3

Right now I have a piece of code (below) which allows me to play audio files on button click. However, I would like to have the file playing in a infinite loop until I click click the button "Stop" button.
How can I achieve that?

```
var audiotypes={
    "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
    "mp4": "audio/mp4",
    "ogg": "audio/ogg",
    "wav": "audio/wav"
}

function ss_soundbits(sound){
    var audio_element = document.createElement('audio')
    if (audio_element.canPlayType){
        for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            var source_element = document.createElement('source')
            source_element.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
            if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                source_element.setAttribute('type', audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
            audio_element.appendChild(source_element)
        }
        audio_element.load()
        audio_element.playclip=function(){
            audio_element.pause()
            audio_element.currentTime=0
            audio_element.play()
        }
        return audio_element
    }
}

var audio = ss_soundbits('audio/file.mp3');

var start_audio= function() {
   audio.playclip();
};
```

Comment: There is a boolean attribute `loop` (not `loup`)... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Capture the `ended` event on the audio element, and then make it play again.

```
audio_element.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
```

This should be sufficient for you.

**edit**

As pointed out by @A. Wolff, I made an oversight wherein clicking stop would fire the ended event. Setting a global boolean flag will resolve this.

```
var stopped = false;

audio_element.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if(!stopped){
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }
}, false); 

var stop_button = document.getElementByID('stop');

stop.addEventListener('click', function(){
    stopped = true
    audio_element.stop();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't method `stop()` fire the `ended` event too?

Comment: @A.Wolff You are right, I've resolved that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my comment - only addition: *audio_element.play()* may not work on mobile browsers without manual click